# Проблема с условием вывода из БД в PHP

Tags: php, html

Есть проблема, мучаюсь уже второй день:

```
if ($row['all_cash'] >= 0) {
echo '<progress value="' . $row['all_cash'] . '" max="10000">';
}
```

Проблема в том, что если я ставлю `$row['all_cash'] >= 0` больше нуля, то условие не выполняется, хотя значение в БД равно 179. Также в `value` не добавляется значение из БД. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: `var_dump($row);`

Comment: в БД то оно мб и 179, но в `row` его явно нет.

Comment: var_dump($row); выводит int(57643)

Comment: @Prohor072 ну вот, и где тут намёк на 179? более того, где тут намёк на `all_cash`?